# How to move the dropdown toggle in the bootstrap to the far right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

Like here is my example, I build some custom Component based on Bootstrap and here use the `dropdown-toggle` class. I got some requirement to move the triangle to the far right, how could I achieve that? Appreciate to the help of any kinds.

my current code snippet:

```
<a title="Click for details" href="javascript: void 0" aria-expanded="true" id="-href" class="text-dark card-header dropdown-toggle" style="">
                <h3 class="inline">example</h3>
            </a>
```

Desired output[image]

Regards.

Comment: Show the code and the desired output.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Sorry, please see my latest edit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to build an [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example) you could use that and just add the arrow-down icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using absolute position on the `::after` pseudo-element and position it to the right; in order for the link to use the full width, you also need to add `d-block` class to it so it behaves as a block level element. You can also use the class `w-100` to explicitly state that you want its width to be 100% of its parent's width.

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 45%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a title="Click for details" href="javascript: void 0" aria-expanded="true" class="w-100 d-block text-dark card-header dropdown-toggle">
  <span class="inline">Example</span>
</a>
```

---

There some other ways you can do this, like using `margin` on the element; but it seems to me that you are trying to build something like a [Bootstrap Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example) so I'm curious why you can't use that component instead.

```css
.triangle {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: .3rem solid;
    border-right: .3rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: .3rem solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0 d-flex align-items-center">
        <button class="btn btn-link w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
        <span class="triangle"></span>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```